# Little spell check boxes have appeared. How can I turn them off?

Tags: microsoft-word

Little spell check boxes have appeared in Word and Outlook. This has been happening for about 2 months. They offer alternative words or spellings for nearly every word I type.

It's driving me crazy!

I have turned off spellcheck so I'm not sure what to do next. I am working with Windows 11 and Office 2019.

[image: this is a screen shot of my problem]

Comment: This is a new feature in Word, not universally loved. You cannot turn it off except by turning off spell checking as you type. Send feedback to MS.

Comment: Office 2019 shouldn’t be getting a new Office feature. It’s feature set is static. The screenshot isn’t even Office, it’s Firefox, so it couldn’t possibly be associated with Office.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that Text Prediction is on.

A. In Windows 11, open Settings -> Time & language -> Typing. Disable "Show text suggestions when typing on the physical keyboard"

[image: Show text suggestions when typing on the physical keyboard options in Settings app]

B. For Ms Word, follow the steps as described [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/editor-text-predictions-in-word-7afcb4f3-4aa2-443a-9b08-125a5d692576#ID0EBBD=Office_365):

> 1. On the status bar, choose Text Predictions: On.
>
> [image: Text Prediction on the status bar]
>
> 2. Switch off Show text predictions while typing.
>
> [image: Show text predictions while typing - in the Options dialog box]

You will find the second option under File -> Options -> Advanced.

Comment: @CharlesKenyon - The author’s problem has nothing to do with Office, their screenshot, is of Firefox.  Additionally, new features, are not even added to Office 2019.

Comment: @Ramhound, you are likely right about it being a Windows problem. However, recently the Editor has been showing up in Word 2016! This is likely a mistake in updates by MS but it does happen.

Comment: @CharlesKenyon - Office 2019, Office 2016, and Office 2021 don’t receive new features. Windows does.

Comment: @Ramhound You are mistaken. I agree that they are not supposed to change, but they do. It is an error by Microsoft in updates where code from Microsoft 365 gets distributed to the wrong programs. It does happen. This has happened for years, and recently with the Editor and spell-checking code. In a later update, they pull the code for the feature. I am a moderator on the Microsoft site and have observed this with both PowerPoint and Word.

Comment: "where code from Microsoft 365" - I have only seen this when the user is also subscribed to Microsoft 365 and installed a perpetual license Office.. You say I am wrong but, how is an Office feature, effecting Firefox? The Office feature described in this answer only effects Office.